# Loop through child items and get image field for showing on parent's view/template

Tags: plone

I have a parent content type RetailFont, it has child types, and one is called FontWeight. 
Fontweight has an image field called WeightImage.

I have successfully added a new view and template for RetailFont (called FontWeightView). I would like to loop through and show some of the fields for all the WeightImage items inside it, such as its title and ImageField.

I tried copying folder_summary_view.pt contents to my template file but it generates errors.
Does it need something in my FontWeightView.py file to work? http://www.pastie.org/3286449

Answer (score 3):

`test()` is a deprecated page template method and should no longer be used.

You can work around this with the logic:

```
<tal:something condition="python:somecond and ifistrue or ifisfalse" />
```

Comment: I already have a condition attribute.
<a href="#"
       tal:condition="exists:item_object/image_thumb"
       tal:attributes="href python:test(item_type in use_view_action, item_url+'/view', item_url)">
Can it be combined?

Comment: does the condition determine if the tag exists, or if the tag's attribute exists?

Comment: Because folder_summary_view.pt is a page template built using old way and does not have view class. They have different mechanisms and using this kind of way of doing things is no longer encouraged.

Comment: The same TAL expressions are valid for all tal:attribute, tal:condition and tal:content